# Largest element in two array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, int

Im trying to write a program that finds the largest element in two arrays. If the arrays contain similar elements it will return the highest of the mutual elements. If the arrays do not contain similar elements it is to return -1. I Have the program 90 percent done. I managed to return the highest numbers, I just can't figure out how to return -1 since we can only do one return statement! any help?

```
    public class finalLargestInCommon
     {
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
         //array declaration
         int [] array1 = {3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 9};
         int [] array2 = {5, 1, 22, 7, 2, 15, 3};
         int [] array3 = {35, 12, 19, 35, 45};
         int [] array4 = {55, 99, 12};
         int [] array5 = {33, 11, 77, 44, 55};
         int [] array6 = {99, 88, 222, 66, 1000};

         System.out.println(LargestInCommon(array1, array2));
         System.out.println(LargestInCommon(array3, array4));
         System.out.println(LargestInCommon(array5, array6));



       }

         public static int LargestInCommon (int [] a, int [] b)
         {
          //variable declaration 
          int i = 0;
          int k = 0;
          int greatest = 0;
          int notPresent = -1;

          for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
           {
            for(k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
            {
              if(a[i] == b[k])
               greatest = a[i];

             }
           }

            return(greatest);


       }


   }
```

Comment: thanks @batty for the edit

Comment: The code doesn't work. Try to change 2nd element of array2 from 1 to 8 and check. This will give you a hint what to improve. And, technically, you can have two or more return statements in one method.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `greatest` to -1 and return `greatest` as you are doing.
If your `if` condition doesn't get hit(which means two similar numbers are not present) `greatest` will have value -1 which will be returned.

```
public static int LargestInCommon (int [] a, int [] b)
         {
          //variable declaration 
          int i = 0;
          int k = 0;
          int greatest = -1;

          for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
           {
            for(k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
            {
              if(a[i] == b[k])
               greatest = a[i];

             }
           }

            return greatest;


       }
```

Comment: Note that this still will not produce the correct answer.  It just happens to work on the input arrays he's using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, sort both and then loop through to find the similar element:

```
public static int maximumSimilar(int[] a, int[] b){
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);
    for(int i = a.length-1; i>=0;i--){
        for(int j = b.length-1;j>=0;j--){
            if(b[j]==a[i]){
                return b[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int LargestInCommon(int[] a, int[] b) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        map.put(a[i],0);
    }
    int greatest = -1;
    if(map.containsKey(b[0])) greatest = b[0];
    for(int i=1;i<b.length;i++) {
        if(map.containsKey(b[i])){
           if(greatest < b[i])
                greatest = b[i];
        }
    }
    return greatest;
}
```

Put elements from an array in a map/Table, while traversing second array check if map has elements from this array and update greatest accordingly. The above method does this and returns -1 if no mutual elements